# Subscribing to SharePoint Alerts via button/link

Tags: alert

I want to create a link /button on my SharePoint home page which effectively subscribe current user to an Alert that I have set on a particular **list/library**.

I want to achieve it using JS/Jquery.

The alerts notifies subscribed user of any change in the list.

Comment: Will this list always be the same so that you only want to have the default "Alert Me" function of your list at a page as a special button?

Comment: @Moe.I have set an Alert on a list using "Alert Me" function. When a new item is added it sends an email notification to me. So when other users are visiting the site I want a button which subscribes to this  particular alert . So when they hit subscribe button they should also get the same email notifications that I am getting .

Comment: Just something about the background - what you are looking for is a custom button on a page which sets alert to a specific list. The alerts in SharePoint are per user, so you are not attempting to "subscribe for the same alert", but instead to "subscribe for a new alert". About how to implement this custom button is something I don't have for you to suggest right now.

Comment: Okay. So what you mean is that User A has to set his own new alert on the particular list in order to receive the email notifications rather subscribing to User B's alert on the same list? Aint there any work around?

Comment: Yes, that's how it goes. I'll continue in the form of answer as there actually might be a simple solution for this one.

Comment: Thanks Moe.Appreciate your help!Let me know if you find one.To give you some idea of what I am trying to do.May be its quite wayward from the actual solution.

Comment: Ahmed, did you catch the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the alerts in SharePoint are per user, so you are not attempting to "subscribe for the same alert", but instead to "subscribe for a new alert".

If you want to create a custom button the users can click to subscribe for specific list, create your HTML button with a link to the following URL:

`https://sharepointsite/_layouts/15/SubNew.aspx?List=%ID%7D&Source=%2F_layouts%2F15%2FMySubs%2Easpx`

In this URL the `ID` is the ID of your list. You can rather easily get this URL by accessing to `https://sharepointsite/_layouts/15/SubChoos.aspx`, selecting the wanted list and clicking *Next*. The URL on the following page is what you are looking for. Note that if your list is on a subsite, you should adjust the URLs to include the path to the subsite.